# Random normalised variable generation

Tags: random, distributions, simulation

I want to generate 8 random variables (in reality to form 4 complex numbers) such that the sum of the 8 variables squared is equal to unity. The aim of generating such numbers is to perform a quantum simulation of 4 qubits (thus the 8 parameters). I've been trying to use `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[]]`, but I'm not quite sure how to satisfy the constraint previously described.

Comment: If you needed to do this by hand (and not with Carl's answer), the approach is similar. Just think of a circle. You randomly choose an angle `[0,2Pi]` and then you calculate the point on the circle with `{Cos[phi],Sin[phi]}`. This automatically has your condition. Now you extend this into 8 dimensions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`RandomPoint`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint) of a [`Sphere`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sphere):

```
SeedRandom[1]
RandomPoint[Sphere[{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}]]
Norm @ %
```

> {0.218453, 0.184026, 0.117791, 0.285912, 0.694608, 0.304419, 0.0587873, \
>   0.494151}
>
> 1.

Comment: `RandomPoint @ Sphere @ 8` is shorter.